# Using the before function in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery and having a problem with the `before` function. What I'm doing is I have table with a class of `fish` and using `detach` to remove it and put it into an array so that when I hit a button it will restore it back to its original place. Here is what I have below. The end result im trying to accomplish is putting text(Pan-Fried Halibut) back into the table. Any help with be very much appreciated

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="fish">Pan-Fried Halibut</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the jQuery detach function:

```
$("input#btn1").click(function () {
    $f = $(".fish").detach();
});
```

Trying to put the text back in:

```
$("input#btn2").click(function () { 
    $(".fish").first().before($f);  'This statement doesnt work; what am i doing wrong
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? We're not mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do here.

One problem is that after you do `$(".fish").detach()` no elements with class fish will remain in the DOM tree. Therefore, when later you do `$(".fish")` nothing will be matched and therefore nothing will be inserted.

Another issue is that you seem to attach both `click` handlers to the same element; both will be called when the button is clicked, and it's not obvious what the end result will be.

Finally, how does `$f` pass from the first event handler to the second?

You would see some result (probably not your intended though) if you did it this way:

```
$(function() {
    var $f; // so that it's accessible to both event handlers

    // bind two handlers to the click event, to be executed on alternating clicks
    $("input#btn1").toggle(function () {
        $f = $(".fish").detach();
    }, function() {
        // you need to find some appropriate selector here, $(".fish")
        // will match nothing because those elements have already been detached
        $(/*something*/).first().before($f);  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think variable `$f` is still in scope when you're trying to add the text back in. Try something like this instead:

```
$("input#btn1").click(function(){
    var $f = $(".fish").first();
    $(".fish").before($f);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you detach .fish, it is no longer there. So you cannot refer to it and try to put it back. Try to put it back by providing a different location. Try to see this example - http://jsfiddle.net/mnNfH/